# How to modify specific columns using sed

Tags: sed, addition

How to modify a specific folumn by sed, especially apply add numeric numbers to that column data.

I have a csv file looks like this:

```
c1,c2,123,c4
c1,c2,345,c4
```

is it possible to add 400 to column 3 of each row?
and makes the result look like the below:

```
c1,c2,523,c4
c1,c2,745,c4
```

I tried by myself using

```
"sed -n 's/[0-9]\{3\}/&+400/ p' test.csv "
```

and the result is

```
c1,c2,123+400,c4
c1,c2,345+400,c4
```

Comment: You might want to look at using `awk` instead, specifying `OFS=','` to set the separator, e.g. `awk OFS=',' $1,$2,$3+400,$4`

Comment: If you truly want `sed`, [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36949/addition-with-sed) might be of some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^,]*/$((&+400))/3;s/.*/echo "&"/e' file
```

This uses a combination of sed and Bash.

Answer (score 5):

`awk` is more suited here:

```
awk '{$3+=400}1' FS=, OFS=, file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F, 'OFS="," {$3 += 400; print}' yourfile.csv
```